# Screensaver not working in 14.10

Tags: unity, 14.10, screensaver, gnome-screensaver

After the upgrade to trusty my screensaver stopped working. Gnome screensaver's settings tell it to start only on Gnome sessions (`OnlyShowIn=GNOME` and `AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome` in autostart/gnome-screensaver.desktop).

I configure it in the Brightness & Lock settings dialog but it doesn't work. I can only lock the screen manually via `Ctrl-Alt-L`.

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line:

```
AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome
```

from `gnome-screensaver.desktop`. It fixes this issue for me.

Comment: Doing this starts the daemon... but the screen still doesn't lock.